# Window re-sizes when making column elements visible, but does not re-size when hiding row elements PySimpleGUI

Tags: row, addition, pysimplegui

I am creating a program that is used to log time. Upon startup it shows one row for entry and allows the user to add rows as needed. The extra rows are hidden at first and shown when the user hits the '+' button, when this happens, the window expands.

There is also the option to remove row elements using a '-' button, however, when this is done, the window does not shrink.

I'm fairly new to PySimpleGUI and am not sure how this would be implemented. Following is the code used to add and remove rows as needed:

```
if event == '-AddRow-':
    NumberOfRows += 1
    window['-Column' + str(NumberOfRows) + '-'].update(visible=True)
           
if event == '-SubtractRow-':
    NumberOfRows -= 1
    window['-Column' + str(NumberOfRows) + '-'].update(visible=False)
```

[Example of my what my program is currently doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOtDo.gif)

Comment: No code for the layout, also no question asked here.

Answer (score 1):

The space for a container, like a row or a Column element will still be occupied if `visible=False` and nothing in the container. Use helper function `sg.pin` in your layout, it will put a small element in the container.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Button('+'), sg.Button('-')]] + [
    [sg.pin(sg.Input(visible=(i==0), key=('INPUT', i)))] for i in range(10)
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

i = 0   # Maximum index for visible element

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == '+':
        i = min(9, i+1)
        window[('INPUT', i)].update(visible=True)

    elif event == '-':
        i = max(0, i-1)
        window[('INPUT', i+1)].update(visible=False)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem perfectly.  What I was seeing was that when I dynamically made images visible and invisible in a Column, the window would grow when the images were added, but not shrink when they were made invisible.

Comment: The container won't automatically shrink if nothing or everything invisible in it.